# RegExp: X number of matches => X number of replacements?

Tags: c#, regex, actionscript-3

Using regular expressions I'm trying to match a string, which has a substring consisting of unknown number of repeats (one or more) and then replace the repeating substring with the same number of replacement strings.

If the Regexp is `"(st)[a]+(ck)"`, then I want to get these kind of results:

```
"stack" => "stOck"
"staaack" => "stOOOck" //so three times "a" to be replaced with three times "O"
"staaaaack" => "stOOOOOck"
```

How do I do that?

Either C# or AS3 would do.

Comment: The easiest way is to use replace function with callback method. For C#: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cft8645c.aspx. Don't know for AS3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For AS3 you can pass a `function` to the [replace](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html#replace%28%29) method on the [`String`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html) object where matching elements are into the `arguments` array. So you can build and return a new String with all the 'a' replaced by 'O'

for example:

```
        // first way explicit loop
        var s:String="staaaack";
        trace("before", s);
        var newStr:String = s.replace(/(st)(a+)(ck)/g, function():String{
          var ret:String=arguments[1]; // here match 'st'
          //arguments[2] match 'aaa..'
          for (var i:int=0, len:int=arguments[2].length; i < len; i++)
             ret += "O";
          return ret + arguments[3]; // arguments[3] match 'ck'
        });
        trace("after", newStr); // output stOOOOck

        // second way array and join
        var s1:String="staaaack staaaaaaaaaaaaack stack paaaack"
        trace("before", s1)
        var after:String = s1.replace(/(st)(a+)(ck)/g, function():String{
            return arguments[1]+(new Array(arguments[2].length+1)).join("O")+arguments[3]
        })
        trace("after", after)
```

here live example on wonderfl : http://wonderfl.net/c/bOwE

Answer (score 1):

If you use .net you can do this

```
find:    (?<=\bsta*)a(?=a*ck\b)
replace: o
```

If you want to change all sta+ck that are substring of other words, only remove the `\b`

Comment: I think `\b` is not necessary. Other than that, this regex should work in C#.

Comment: @nhahtdh: I wanted to be sure not to make a mistacke

Comment: Nah, I don't know. OP's regex doesn't include `\b`, so I don't think it is needed either. In fact, it will change the result. For example `stackoverflow` with OP's regex may become `stOckoverflow`, but yours will not do any replacement.

Answer (score 1):

Since I am not familiar with either C# or AS3, I will write a solution in JavaScript, but the concept in the solution can be used for C# code or AS3 code.

```
var str = "stack stackoverflow staaaaaack stOackoverflow should not replace";
var replaced = str.replace(/st(a+)ck/g, function ($0, $1) {
    var r = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < $1.length; i++) {
        r += "O";
    }
    return "st" + r + "ck";
});
```

Output:

```
"stOck stOckoverflow stOOOOOOck stOackoverflow should not replace"
```

In C#, you would use [`Regex.Replace(String, String, MatchEvaluator)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cft8645c.aspx) (or other `Regex.Replace` methods that takes in a `MatchEvaluator` delegate) to achieve the same effect.

In AS3, you can pass a function as replacement, similar to how I did above in JavaScript. Check out the documentation of [`String.replace()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html#replace%28%29) method.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the [String Replace()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx) method instead?

```
var str = "stack";
str = str.Replace("a", "O");
```

Comment: This will not work very well on the input `should not replace anything` - since the `a` must be between `st` and `ck`

Comment: @nhahtdh The OP only mentions that `substring consisting of unknown number of repeats` must be replaced with `replacement strings`. The position of the substring has not been mentioned explicitly and I'm not sure if it is implied, hence the suggestion.

Comment: But you should note that the example given has "prefix" and "suffix" before and after the repetition. Simply replacing all `a` with `O` is not going to be correct.

Comment: nhahtdh is correct - `a` must be between `st` and `ck`, it wouldn't make much sense if I was asking how to make as simple replace operation as `replace("a", "o")`.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
       String s = "Staaack";

        Console.WriteLine(s);

        while (Regex.Match(s,"St[O]*([a]{1})[a]*ck").Success){
            s = Regex.Replace(s,"(St[O]*)([a]{1})([a]*ck)", "$1O$3");
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(s);


        Console.ReadLine();
```

it replaces one a with every iteration, until no more as can be found.

Comment: No. This is wrong. I don't think `stxxack` should be replaced.

Comment: @nhahtdh then replace `[^a]*` in the front with `[O]*`, so it will only replace st____cks containing a's or O's

Comment: No, it is also wrong. If the initial input is `stOack`, the original regex would not match, and no replace would happen.